# Python Pickle: what can cause stack index out of range error?

Tags: python, pickle

I'm getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 1374, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 1075, in load_obj
    k = self.marker()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\pickle.py", line 874, in marker
    while stack[k] is not mark: k = k-1
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Why could this be happening?

Comment: Sorry, I figured it out already. Never mind.

Comment: If it's a problem that someone else might have you should post an answer yourself and accept it; if not you should probably delete the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: I was trying to call `pickle.loads()` on the uninitialized field of a Google App Engine model.

Answer (score 1):

A "damaged file" is the general explanation; single most likely cause is that you forgot to open the file (in Windows) as `'rb'` ("read binary") and the pickling was done with a binary protocol (i.e., any protocol except the old, slow default protocol 0, ascii only, that basically exists only for legacy purposes, makes larger files, and has several limitations).